# Adding dynamic form data to ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Say i have a form in html with the following content

```
<form>
    <div id="si-main">
        <button id="si-btn">Add new content</button>
        <div class="si-content">
            <input type="text" class="si-input" name="content"> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="si-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now i wanna append the ".si-content" div when i click the "#si-btn" i do that using this script in JS

```
$('#si-btn').click(function() {
    $('#si-main').append('<div class="si-content"><input type="text" class="si-input" name="content"></div>')
})
```

I then submit the form like this in JS

```
$('form #si-submit').click(function() {
    var data_to_send = {}
    $('form').find('.si-input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('si-input')) {
            data_to_send[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()      
        }
    })
    //NEXT I SEND THE AJAX REQUEST AND HANDLE THE RESPONSE
})
```

Now the problem is each i append it adds a new "si-content" div. But when i send the data it only sends the content of the first div. Can someone tell me what would be the best way add the data in this case ?

Comment: Use [`$('form').serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: you have to give unique `name` to each `input` box otherwise `data_to_send[]` will hold only single record. Try giving different-different names to each dynamic input box each time while appending.

Comment: `<input type="text" class="si-input" name="content">` does not have a `value` attribute ?

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
 $('#si-main').append('<div class="si-content"><input type="text" class="si-input" name="content[]"></div>');

$('form #si-submit').click(function() {
    var data_to_send =  $(this).parent('form').serialize();

    //NEXT SEND THE AJAX REQUEST AND HANDLE THE RESPONSE
})
```